# AttributeErrorr: module 'glm' has no attribute 'vec2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, librería, python-import

En mi código estoy importando la librería `glm` y al intentar usar su clase `vec2` me manda este error:

```
AttributeError: module 'glm' has no attribute 'vec2'.
```

ya desinstalé e instalé la librería, la actualicé, no tengo archivos con el nombre glm.py, le di mi código a chat-gpt y supuestamente debería de funcionar, he hecho de todo, aquí parte del código:

```
import glm
import math


MAJOR_VER, MINOR_VER = 3, 3
DEPTH_SIZE = 24
NUM_SAMPLES = 1  


WIN_RES = glm.vec2(1600,900)
```

Answer (score 0):

El codigo es correcto, sospecho que el problema es que no has instalado el paquete correcto o tienes un conflicto entre varios, y no creo que seas el primero si es el caso:

En PyPI existe [un paquete que se llama `glm`](https://pypi.org/project/glm/) pero que nada tiene que ver con hacer operaciones matemáticas sobre OpenGL. Dicho paquete se instala con `pip intall glm` y se importa usando el mismo identificador, `import glm`.

El paquete que tu necesitas es [`PyGLM`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/), que se instala mediante `pip intall pyglm` y usa exactamente el mismo identificador al importar que el anterior, `import glm`.

Si has instalado el primer paquete por error, lo cual es bastante comprensible dicho sea de paso, debes desinstalarlo e instalar PyGLM, en la terminal:

```
python -m pip uninstall glm
python -m pip install pyglm
```

Si no has sido tu, sino que `pip` ha instalado `glm` como dependencia de otro paquete, si ese paquete no es necesario en tu proyecto actual crea un entorno virtual nuevo limpio e instala solo lo necesario.

Si por un casual necesitaras los dos paquetes la cosa se complica, una posibilidad es indicarle a `pip` con la opción de instalación `--prefix` que los instale en directorios separados, adaptando luego los imports adecuadamente y cuidando de no romper las dependencias.

Idealmente, alguno de los dos autores debería cambiar el identificador de su paquete para evitar este conflicto.